# Searching for a pptx and pdf viewer

Tags: 7

I'm using Embedded Google Docs Viewer but it's not what I need exactly.
I searched for a while but I could not find my answer.
I need a module that displays the .pdf or .ppt file like in this image.

[image: screenshot]

Can anybody suggest me a module?

Comment: Arranging files in a certain layout is a vastly different problem from embedding a certain file type into the browser.

Comment: I don't think the question is about arranging files in a certain layout. Both .pdf and .ppt files are files splitting the content in pages, and the OP wants to show those files allowing the user to move to different pages  that are shown as thumbnail.

Comment: pdf.js can show already pdf files in browsers, there is also a viewer, there are some modules like http://drupal.org/project/pdf_reader http://drupal.org/project/gdoc_field

Comment: @abd: have you got any solution or answer ?

Comment: no not yet, i couldn't find what i looked for, but i used drupal.org/project/gdoc_field

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your PDF to a series of images and show them as slideshow, using the [PDF To ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/pdf_to_imagefield) module.

> The PDF To ImageField module provides automatic conversion of uploaded PDF files to images.
>   It can be used either to create a snapshot of the front page to use as a preview thumbnail, or to generate a gallery of images from each page in the document.
>
> The module is implemented as CCK widget for FileField where PDFs are uploaded to. It places generated images into a CCK ImageField on the same content type.

Comment: also you can use pdf.js to manipulate pdf files.